# How to change the first child's style coming from a DataTemplate in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

So I have a DataTemplate defined in my Page.Resources which is used inside a GridView to Display my Data.

It's basically the same as in the GroupedItemsPage Template coming with VS 2012.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="menuGroupTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="itemSquare" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250" Tapped="itemSquare_Tapped">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now this makes my groups look like this:

[image: Linear ordered items]

All items look the same way, squares all the same size!

Now I would like to create a DataTemplate which makes the first items in a group a lot bigger that the rest so that it would look like this: (derived from IdeaPress Wordpress apps)

[image: Different ordered items]

So now I would like to change the style/look/size of the first element in my group, but I just can't find a way to retrieve the first element and change it's size.

The problem with the Ideapress App is that it's completely written in HTML/JS while I'm using C# and they're not using any DataTemplate or similar things to display their data, so simply copying it from them didn't work out for me. At least both are windows store apps.

I thought about doing it in the constructor, which failed just as some other scenarios. 
But as I got the feeling, there must be a different, more elegant way to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two different templates for doing this.
This [link](http://win8template5.codeplex.com/) is useful and provides a sample of doing what you need in an elegant way.

Comment: After a while of playing around with the project you recommended I finally found the solution for my problem, I will post a custom UI element inspired from what you pointed me to later here!